# jQuery selection is not working for addClass but is for hasClass

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why the jQuery is not adding the class "taken" to the div following the input in the following html:

```
<div id='location-inventory'>
<input type="text" class='bin_number_input'>
<div></div>
</div>
```

In the following jQuery, the console.log is being activated but the addClass is doing nothing.

jQuery:

```
$('#location-inventory').on('keyup','.bin_number_input',function(){

  if(!$(this).next().hasClass("taken")){
    console.log("can update");  // <- this is working
    $(this).next().addClass("taken");
  }else{
```

How would I make it so that the div becomes `<div class='taken'></div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `.` before first `next()` to chain your selector:

```
if(!$(this).next().hasClass("taken")){
// ------- ^ here
```

Also make sure you've closed the `else` clause and `keyup` function properly.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2Dt2/)**

Comment: thx, I can't really argue with the fiddle but not working for me. The html fragment above is actually being written after the dom has loaded. Should this effect it? I wouldn't think so but that seems to be the only difference between what you have and what I have. here's a jsbin and looks like it's working. http://jsfiddle.net/nCh46/

Comment: ignore that last jsfiddle